# Find $x$ such that $4\sqrt x+\sqrt 2=3\sqrt 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Would anyone be able to show me how to solve the question below?

Given the function $$f(x)=4\sqrt x+\sqrt 2$$

Find $t$ such that $$f(t)=3\sqrt 2$$

Comment: This isn't clear, at least not to me.  Are you integrating something?  What?  You say you want a root...which suggests that you are trying to solve something like $f(x)=0$, but I can't guess what function you have in mind.

Comment: Ah, I see from the edit that you are just trying to find $x$ such that $4\sqrt x+\sqrt 2 = 3\sqrt 2$.  Poor notation...I will edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Now, where do you get stuck?   $4\sqrt t+\sqrt 2 = 3\sqrt 2 \implies 4\sqrt t=2\sqrt 2$.  Does that help?

Comment: I got there although I'm not sure what to do after that?

Comment: Well, Isolate the $t$.  $\sqrt t =\frac {\sqrt 2}2$.  Now how can we undo the square root?

Comment: Take it over and square it?  I didn't realise I could take the 4 over without taking the square root of t over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question the variables **t** and **x** are the same thing so **x=t**
In order for us to find the right value of x that makes the function equal **3√2**

We will solve the equation 4√x + √2 = 3√2

Implies : 4√x = 2√2

Implies : 2√x = √2

Implies :  √x = (√2)/2

Implies :(√x)²= ((√2)/2)²

Hence   :   x = 1/2

Computing f(1/2) :

f(1/2) = 4√(1/2) + √2

f(1/2) = 4/√2 + √2

f(1/2) = (4+2)/√2

f(1/2) = 6/√2

f(1/2) = (6√2)/2

f(1/2) = 3√2

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful :)

Comment: I'm very touched :)

Comment: Nicely answered.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank You ! I will definitely learn it !

Answer (score 2):

You have $f(x)$.You have to find a suitable $f(t)$.This means when you plug in $t$ for every value of $x$ so that the result becomes $3\sqrt2$.

If $f(x)=4\sqrt x+\sqrt 2$ then $f(t)=4\sqrt t+\sqrt 2$.

Now,solve.
$$4\sqrt t+\sqrt2=3\sqrt2$$

$$4\sqrt t=2\sqrt2$$

$$\sqrt t=\frac {1}{\sqrt2}$$

$$t=\frac 12$$.

You can back-calculate to check $f(\frac12)=3\sqrt2$

Comment: Since the op is trying to solve for $t$, you should probably replace every x  by to, so that $f(t) = 4\sqrt t + \sqrt 2 = 3\sqrt 2$, so in the end, $t = \frac 12$

Comment: @amWhy I'm writing this from my mobile lying in the hospital bed down with fever....not in a position to edit it...thanks for your suggestion though...will try to do it once I am back home....